# How to make crypto-js encryption functionality machine independent?

Tags: typescript, encryption, cryptojs

I am new to this [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) library (and node.js in general), and I am using it for UI test automation, logging in via a service account.  I have the following class

```
import credsJson from './creds.json';
import * as crypto from 'crypto-js';
import passKey from './passKey.json';


export class Utility {

 getCredentials(): Credentials{

    let creds = new Credentials();
    creds.userName = credsJson.userName;
    let encoded = credsJson.password;
    creds.password = crypto.AES.decrypt(encoded, passKey.passKey).toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);
    return creds;    
}

encryptPassword(){
    var encrypted = crypto.AES.encrypt(credsJson.password, passKey.passKey).toString();
}
}

export class Credentials {
    userName: string;
    password: string;
}
```

which I reference from a test method in Debug mode that encrypts the password in `creds.json` and I am able to get the new encrypted password to replace it with.

```
test.describe('ChangePassword', () => {
  test('test encryption', async () => {
var pass = new Utility();
pass.encryptPassword();
```

Everything works fine.  My question is, is there any way to make this machine independent?  The service account and password are the same, but if I want to execute this on 3 machines I need to do the encryption 3 times (once per machine) since the resulting encrypted password seems to be unique.  Just wondering if there is a way around that, or if that's how it should be behaving.

Comment: Is `passKey.passKey` a **string**? If so, cryptojs treats it as password and **does password-based encryption**. PBE uses random salt which makes _every_ encryption different -- if you do it multiple times on the _same_ machine, _or_ on different machines (necessarily multiple times). If you want a fixed result, use an actual key _and_ IV (if needed, and it is here) as WordArray objects per [a copy of the documentation](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  thanks, yes it is a string.  I will look into the documentation you provided.